# How to add description to parameters of command in discord.py?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, bots

Let's say that i have this command:

```
@bot.command(description='command do some stuff')
async def somecommand(ctx: commands.Context, arg1:str, arg2:str = "hello"):
    await ctx.channel.send(arg1+arg2)
```

And when I call help command: `!help somecommand` or ?help somecommand (depends on prefix)
it returns:

[image]

**How can I add description to arguments?**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `commands.parameter()` as the value, and set the `description` kwarg. Only difference is that to give it a default value you now have to use the `default` kwarg of `commands.parameter()` instead of directly passing it in the function.

```py
async def some_command(ctx, arg1: str = commands.parameter(default="Here be default", description="Here be description"))
```

Docs with an example: https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ext/commands/api.html#discord.ext.commands.parameter