# How do I add a description to an argument in a Discord slash command (Python)

Tags: discord

I'm the `discord.ext` library, and using the `@bot.tree.command` decorator. I've found that if I just use the `@bot.command` decorator then the command doesn't sync on_ready. I've added a description to the command itself, but I wanted to add a description to the optional argument it accepts. Code is below.

```
@client.tree.command(name="command", description="test command")
async def scores(interaction: discord.Interaction, date: str=datetime.now(tz).strftime('%Y-%m-%d')):
    await interaction.response.send_message(str("\n".join(testcommand.getinfo(date))))
```

I saw [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74306864/how-to-add-description-to-parameters-of-command-in-discord-py) that shows how to do it, but it only works with the `@bot.command` decorator. Trying it with `@bot.tree.command` fails.

Answer (score 0):

I've figured out my own problem! There is a decorator to do this.

`@discord.app_commands.describe(date = "Date in YYYY-MM-DD format")`

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively you can use docstrings to add description for both your command the parameters

Example

```
@app_commands.command(name="my_command")
async def command(interaction: Interaction, a: int, b: str):
    """my command description

    Args:
        x (int): my first parameter description
        b (str): my second parameter description
    """
    pass
```